# Dispose() - What call this and when

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, idisposable

I have this piece of code:

```
using (var img = Bitmap.FromFile(path))
{
    result = new Bitmap(img);
}
```

Questions:

1. Is the `Bitmap` instance immediately called at the end of the using? or is it waiting to be garbage collected?
2. Is it disposed from the current thread or another?

Comment: `You can achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the using statement is translated by the compiler.` from [mdsn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). So this means the GC depends on the dispose method.

Comment: Disposal has nothing to do with garbage collection.  Disposal is about cleaning up *unmanaged* resources that the GC *can't* keep track of.

Comment: @gunr2171: The GC knows nothing about `Dispose`. Not sure how you came to that conclusion.

Comment: @leppie, didn't know, made a guess. And now I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually have *two* Bitmap instances - `img` and `result`.

`img` will get disposed (I believe on the current thread) at the end of the `using` block. The compiler inserts a `Dispose` call in a `finally` block for you.

`result` does NOT get disposed automatically - whatever *consumes* result will need to dispose of it.

Also note that getting disposed and garbage collected are two different things - `Dispose` will clean up any *unmanaged* resources immediately (in the case of a Bitmap it will be the underlying graphics objects), but any *managed* resources will be garbage collected as some later, undetermined time.

Comment: @glautrou I'm 95% sure it does but can't prove it - if someone can prove me wrong I won't be offended :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is equivalent to the following (which is actually how the code is translated by the compiler):

```
try
{
    var img = Bitmap.FromFile(path);
    result = new Bitmap(img);
}
finally
{
    img.Dispose();
}
```

Note that `result` never had `Dispose` called on it, and it is up to the calling code to properly dispose of the object.

Answer (score 1):

It is neither garbage collected nor disposed.  You write code like this to create a *deep copy* of a bitmap.  Different from `Bitmap.Clone()` which creates a shallow copy.  You use it to avoid taking a lock on the *path* file.  Such locks can be very troublesome later when you try to save the image back, that fails with a GenericException.

The Bitmap(Image) constructor creates the copy by using Graphics.DrawImage().  The *using* statement on the img variable releases the lock on the file.

This is not entirely without trouble btw, a deep copy costs a lot of memory and can significantly increase the commit size of your process when the image is large.  Or in other words, it is expensive and you'll run the risk of your program bombing with OutOfMemoryException.  There's also a flaw, the Bitmap(Image) constructor forgets to copy the Image.HorizontalResolution and VerticalResolution properties.  So the image might not be displayed at the same size.

Answer (score 0):

`using` is a syntactic sugar for the `try/finally` pattern,  after the brackets is closed the `Img.Dispose();` will be in behind called.

```
using (var img = Bitmap.FromFile(path))
{
   result = new Bitmap(img);
}  // here Dispose will be immediately called.

if you are using img/result here you will get an Exception.
```

Threads have nothing to do with this matter! Dispose called always in the current thread.

Comment: So 'Dispose()` is called from the current thread. Documentation?

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029 check page 392 interface IDisposable and check also the Dispose Pattern.

Comment: @glautrou: Depending on the GC mode, `Dispose` could be called from a different thread.

Comment: @leppie can you post an example or any link this is very importent for me 2. I thought always that the dispose be run in the current thread if you have more info than please put a link!

Comment: @leppie you have right Dispose is not thread safe but you can do that. Check the link Thread safe Dispose + Finalize http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9099127c-413b-48eb-983b-86134e3f2beb/thread-safe-dispose-finalize

Comment: @BassamAlugili: That is probably one good reason to use `using` instead of waiting for the GC to kick in. :)

Comment: @leppie very good info because I lot of ppl says using or dispose is not importent because the GC call that dispose when it need space. BUT THIS IS 100 % bad! thanks

Comment: @BassamAlugili: For single threaded app, I personally do not care, but bringing up the multi-threading point, kind of convinces me ;p